# Change visibility of files for non-root users

Tags: permissions, nautilus, filesystem, root

I have a file that is only visible in root mode. I want to make it visible for non-root users. I added permissions such that the maximum of person can read, write and execute it (even if only read would be necessary) but it is still invisible in non-root (standard) mode. Permissions are as follow for this file (filename.tar.gz)

> -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 2335154 Jan  4 22:55 filename.tar.gz

How can I make this file visible in non-root mode?

Comment: copy your file to another location (use `cp` command ) and see if it's become visible. if not try to change its extension from tar.gz to something else and check the changes and reply **any changes**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It happened that I have put the file on the Desktop folder, but the root folder named Desktop is completely different from the non-root folder Dektop (which is what is displayed on the desktop of Ubuntu). I copied the file by cd into the folder of the file, and using

> cp filename.tar.gz ~/../home/username/Desktop/rosfile.tar.gz

filename being the name of the file, and username being the name of the user. The rights for non-root modification of the file is achieved using

> sudo chown "username" "filename"

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the owner or the group of the file.

```
sudo chgrp "group name" "filename"   
sudo chown "username" "filename"
```

But this should only be done, if the file is not exactly required to be "owned" by the `root`.

Comment: [Here is what I get](http://s29.postimg.org/gbs722j3r/Screen_Shot_01_06_15_at_02_08_AM.jpg). Unfortunately, the problem still remains. You can see on the folder on the left the Desktop folder for non-root users, and on the right the same Desktop folder but for root user.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rw foldername
```

If you want to change all files and folders use:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rw *
```

You can change all these to be owned by the myuser user with:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser *
```

Comment: I tried your hint but I still get the same problem. [Here is what I get](http://s29.postimg.org/gbs722j3r/Screen_Shot_01_06_15_at_02_08_AM.jpg). You can see on the folder on the left the Desktop folder for non-root users, and on the right the same Desktop folder but for root user.

Answer (score 1):

Changing permission for just the file won't do. You need to allow access for the non-root user to all folders in the parent tree of the file in question.

This of course is a security hazard. So, it is recommended that you try to solve the "need" of accessing this file in a secure way.